# como visualizar una imagen en un servidor nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, http, backend

Estoy tratando de visualizar una imagen png/jpg en un servidor hecho en nodejs, ya verifique que la ruta se encuentre bien, pero sigue sin mostrar la imagen y no sé que es lo que pueda estar mal.
Hice lo de poner la imagen en una carpeta public, pero tampoco la muestra
Estoy usando http en nodejs v18.14.2 en Windows.

Parte del codigo es:

```
if(req.method == "GET") {
    const archivo = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url) // Archivo meta (el que se está ejecutando)
    const directorio = path.dirname(archivo) // Recupero mi directorio base
    const ruta = path.join(directorio, req.url) // Ruta absoluta del recurso solicitado
    //const fileStream = createReadStream(ruta, 'UTF-8')
    let fileStream = null

    console.log('Archivo: ', archivo)
    console.log('Directorio: ', directorio)
    console.log('Ruta: ', ruta)


    if(req.url != '/') fileStream = createReadStream(ruta, 'UTF-8')
    if(req.url == '/') readFile('index.html', 'UTF-8', (err, html) => {
        if (err) console.log (err)
        else {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'}) //firma legal de un archivo

            res.end(html)
        }
    })
    else if(req.url.match(/.html$/)) res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'})
    else if(req.url.match(/.css$/)) res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/css'})
    else if(req.url.match(/.js$/)) res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/javascript'})
    //acompletar el traspaso de imagenes
    // else if(req.url.match(/.ico$/)) res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'})
    else if(req.url.match(/.ico$/)) res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon'})
    else if(req.url.match(/.png$/)) res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/png'})
    else {
        pipe = false

        res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'})
        res.end("404 Error: Archivo no encontrado")
    }
    //fileStream.pipe(res) // Envío respuesta fragmentada al cliente (chunk)
    if (req.url != '/' && fileStream) fileStream.pipe(res) // Envío respuesta fragmentada al cliente (chunk)
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]